Cross origin POST request with HTTP only session cookie
In my fastify application, I have a hook that grabs the auth_session to see whether a user is authorized or not:
fastify.addHook('preHandler', async (req, reply) => {
        const sessionId =
            req.cookies[fastify.lucia.luciaInstance.sessionCookieName]

        console.log(`SESSIONID --------------- ${sessionId}`)

        if (sessionId) {
            const { session, user } =
                await fastify.lucia.luciaInstance.validateSession(sessionId)

            if (session && session.fresh) {
                const cookie = fastify.lucia.luciaInstance.createSessionCookie(
                    session.id
                )
                reply.setCookie(cookie.name, cookie.value, cookie.attributes)
            }

            if (!session) {
                reply.clearCookie(fastify.lucia.luciaInstance.sessionCookieName)
            }

            req.user = user
            req.session = session
        } else {
            req.user =
                process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test'
                    ? { id: 'qkj7ld6pgsqvurgfxaao' }
                    : null
            req.session = null
        }
    })

fastify.addHook('preHandler', async (req, reply) => {
        if (
            !req.user &&
            !req.session &&
            !req.url.includes('/account/login') &&
            process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test'
        ) {
            return reply.unauthorized()
        }
    })

When I make a POST request through the Swagger UI to /api/v1/websites and there is an active session, everything works as expected. The data gets POSTed to the datbase.
However, when I make a POST request from my SvelteKit application like so:
createWebsite: async ({ request }) => {
        const data = await request.formData()

        await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/websites', {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                title: data.get('title'),
                metaDescription: data.get('description')
            })
        })
    }

I get the error UnauthorizedError: Unauthorized.
I added a console.log to my hook to log the sessionId variable, and what I have noticed is that when I make a request from SvelteKit, I get two log results in a row, first undefined, and after that the right sessionId. From the swagger UI on the fastify server, I only get the appropriate sessionId, no undefined.
When I make GET requests from my SvelteKit, I do not have this unauthorized issue and the auth_session cookie seems to work just fine.
I read online that in CORS there is some PREFLIGHT request sent before the actual POST request, and suspect that this eventually causes the undefined and does the unauthorized error.
Unfortunately, I have no idea how I would properly work around it. Neither do I know if this is the actual issue.

The POST request you send from SvelteKit is deemed "non-simple" because it includes a Content-Type: application/json header. As such, it is indeed preceded by a preflight request, and such requests do not carry credentials. You need to wrap some CORS middleware around the logic of your hook; and in your CORS configuration, you need to list Content-Type as an allowed request header.

Okay, I wasted one day debugging this. The problem was a single word that I did not include, and that was { fetch } in the SvelteKit action.
So here it did not use SvelteKits internal fetch, but instead the browser standard one.
That is why it did not work haha
If anyone should read this, please keep it in mind as it takes away all the trouble with setting request headers etc. manually:
A special version of fetch is available in load functions, server hooks and API routes for invoking endpoints directly during server-side rendering, without making an HTTP call, while preserving credentials. (To make credentialled fetches in server-side code outside load, you must explicitly pass cookie and/or authorization headers.) It also allows you to make relative requests, whereas server-side fetch normally requires a fully qualified URL.
